# How to inform new users to tag user name when replying

Tags: feature-request, comments

Some new users ask questions and I sometimes reply in the comments. Also, some other users also comment on questions.

We will just comment and close the URL of the question, and if the OP comments again, we don't get the notification because he didn't tag any usernames. This way there are a lot of chances that they may miss help.

How can we avoid this? Can the system make it mandatory to add tags in the comments?

Comment: Mandatory, really? Also, this is [kind of already a thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157965/should-the-site-prompt-new-users-to-include-an-name-in-comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should you ever be curious about what happened to posts you commented on, the easiest thing is to go to your own profile,  click the <kbd>all actions</kbd> link, then filter to <kbd>comments</kbd>. Above each comment you have left is a link to the post on which you left it. You can then see if another comment has been left, the post has been edited, or your comment has been upvoted.

New users learn the @ reply by seeing them. Since not all comments are directed at anyone, trying to automate the process of getting an @ reply into every comment would not be a good use of developer time, imo.