# Automatically inform newcomers of how comment @replies work

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

I often find myself informing the newcomers about the [comment @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/353058), since otherwise the comments they write (when trying to reply to someone) often remain unnoticed due to lack of notifications.

I propose adding an automatic message explaining how the reply system works.

Something like this:

When the user tries to post a comment, if:

- Nobody would get a notification unless they `@mention` someone, i.e.:

  - They're commenting under their own post, **and**
  - At least two other users have commented on the same post (if there was only one user, they will get notified regardless; if there were no other users, we assume that the comment is not directed at anyone in particular), **and**
- The user hasn't dismissed this notification before, **and**
- (optionally) They have <N rep (or any other criteria to avoid showing it to existing long-time users).

**Then** show following text next to the comment textbox:

> When replying to other users, begin your comment with `@username`, otherwise they won't get notified. ([more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019))
>
> <kbd>dismiss</kbd>

I'm not a native speaker, so the message wording can probably be improved.

Comment: Does it do this already? See [this really old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158177/323179)

Comment: Uh...what I find really annoying is being told stuff I know very well over and over again. Mentioning users with an `@` in front is pretty standard thing in many online platforms, I needed to see it *once* in comments to understand what it is about. I don't need to be told this many times until my rep improves. Yes, not everybody is familiar with @-mentions but it's not some hidden knowledge no new user could have, either.

Comment: @VLAZ Note that I suggested not showing it again after the user presses 'dismiss' once, regardless of rep.

Comment: @VLAZ HolyBlackCat also suggests to put this next to the comment bar, so you can simply ignore it, just like the help in the sidebar whenever you post a new question.